# How to add multiple images on top of the background image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a piece of code here which makes up the body of the login and register screens. I added an image at the very top but my question is how do i add multiple images for the body?
I have some images i want to add in different positions for blur effects but whenever  do either nothing shows up or gives me an error about the constraints.
When i add multiple containers with a single image in each one, i get the constraint error.
Everything was added in pubspec.yaml and in the folders correctly.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [Color(0xFF1F1F1F), Color(0xFF1F1F1F)],
          ),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/register.png"),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,

            //fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 250),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              if (onBackPressed == null) verticalSpaceLarge,
              if (onBackPressed != null) verticalSpaceRegular,
              if (onBackPressed != null)
                IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  onPressed: onBackPressed,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  title!,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              verticalSpaceSmall,
              SizedBox(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    subtitle!,
                    style: ktsMediumGreyBodyText,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              verticalSpaceRegular,
              form!,
              if (onForgotPassword != null)
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: onForgotPassword,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password?',
                        style: ktsMediumGreyBodyText.copyWith(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              verticalSpaceRegular,
              if (validationMessage != null)
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    validationMessage!,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: kBodyTextSize),
                  ),
                ),
              if (validationMessage != null) verticalSpaceRegular,
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: onMainButtonTapped,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kcPrimaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  child: busy!
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          mainButtonTitle!,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              verticalSpaceRegular,
              if (onCreateAccountTapped != null)
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: onCreateAccountTapped,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        verticalSpaceMedium,
                        Text(
                          "Don\'t have an account?",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        horizontalSpaceTiny,
                        Text(
                          "SIGN UP",
                          style: TextStyle(color: kcPrimaryColor),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              if (showTermsText!)
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "By signing up you agree to our terms, conditions and privacy policy",
                    style: ktsMediumGreyBodyText,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use stack

Comment: Can you please explain more like where in the app i can add stack?

Comment: can you add an image that you like to archive ?